# Is anonymous auth enabled by default?

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication

I have failed to find some info on this, but it seems that even though I do not force the user to auth(⚠️) at all, it seems as if I call `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser` at least a few seconds after startup, I will get a valid anonymous user back. Does the Firebase SDK log the current user in behind the scenes, or is an unauthed user always regarded anonymous?

⚠️ auth as in:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously() { (user, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Sign in anonymously failed: \(error)")
        return
    }

    if let user = user {
        print("user: \(user), is anon: \(user.isAnonymous), uid: \(user.uid)")
        self.user = user
    }
}
```

**Update 1**: It seems I may be wrong, or there is something *else* important here. It might be the case where a device that has previously signed in will subsequently always (or something... maybe using keychain etc) be treated as signed in, *even if app is deleted between runs*. Investigating...

**Update 2**: So after some investigation  it seems that if we don't sign the user out specifically, the user will likely remain signed in forever OR at least a long time. Even between installs... I swear I tried to delete then install, and the user was still signed in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you must enable anonymous authentication in the Firebase console in the 'Authentication' tab, under 'Sign In Method'

[image]

Comment: That's correct of course, I forgot to mention it. I still suspect Firebase tries to log in the user as anon behind the scenes... or at the very least keeps sessions/credentials/login state between runs/installs.